How to Enable or Disable Tabs Based on Field Value Pattern in Azure DevOps WITD XML
I am customizing a work item type in Azure DevOps and need to enable or disable entire tabs based on the value of a specific field. This field, Abc.CustomField, stores values from a multi-select dropdown and is formatted as a semicolon-separated string (e.g., Abc;Bcd;Cde)
My goal is to:
Enable or disable the tab "InactiveTab" based on whether Abc.CustomField contains specific values or matches a certain pattern.
Is there a way to conditionally enable or disable tabs in Azure DevOps WITD XML based on a field value pattern match? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

According to the document on Work item Rules and rule evaluation, I am afraid that there isn't such a functionality for an XML process to disable the visibility of a work item page based on the value of a field.
Even for an inheritance process, which though has the constraint rule of Hide the field, it is only available when a group membership condition is selected.
I can totally understand your requirement to use the different values in a custom field to control the visibility effective on certain work item layouts. Per the current limitation, you could create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion . That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

Hi @Alvin Zhavo, Is there any work around to achieve this?

Hi there, I am afraid there is no built-in feature to meet your requirement to disable the visibility of a work item page based on the value of a field.
